# Retorna os dados do banco em um JTextField

Tags: java, swing

Estou com uma dúvida com relação a listar os dados que gravei em um banco de dados para um `JTextField`. Criei uma tela, com o campo para o usuário digitar o ID do cadastro no banco e um botão FILTRAR. Quero que, quando clique em filtrar, apareça os dados daquele ID nos `JTextField` que criei.

Segue o Código do botão filtrar e o código de listar do banco.

Filtrar:

```
JButton btnFiltrar = new JButton("Filtrar");
    btnFiltrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            GerenciaAgenda ga = new GerenciaAgenda();
            Agenda a = new Agenda();
            a.setId(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
            ga.selecionar(a.getId());
            txtNome.setText(a.getNome());
            txtEmail.setText(a.getEmail());
            txtCpf.setText(a.getCpf());
        }
    });
```

Metodo para fazer a seleção:

```
public Agenda selecionar(int id){
        Connection c = new Conexao().criarConexao();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM agenda WHERE id=?";
        try {
            PreparedStatement p = c.prepareStatement(sql);
            p.setInt(1, id);

            ResultSet resultado = p.executeQuery();

            if (resultado.next()){
                Agenda a = new Agenda();
                a.setId(id);
                a.setNome( resultado.getString("nome"));
                a.setEmail(  resultado.getString("email"));
                a.setCpf( resultado.getString("cpf"));
                return a;
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GerenciaAgenda.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            new Conexao().fecharConexao(c);    
        }
        return null;
    }
```

No que estou errando ?

Comment: Olá, se alguma das respostas lhe atendeu, seria interessante marcá-la como aceita, assim,servirá de referencia para outros usuarios. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme foi mostrado em outras respostas, o problema está neste trecho:

```
GerenciaAgenda ga = new GerenciaAgenda();
Agenda a = new Agenda();
a.setId(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
ga.selecionar(a.getId());
```

Você está criando um objeto `Agenda` apenas com a propriedade de id, e tentando chamar outras propriedades que não foram setadas neste objeto.

Como sua classe `GerenciaAgenda` retorna um objeto `Agenda`, o correto é atribuir este retorno ao objeto `Agenda`:

```
GerenciaAgenda ga = new GerenciaAgenda();
Agenda a = ga.selecionar(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
```

Assim, você garante que o objeto `a` está na verdade recebendo o retorno do seu método, após consulta no seu banco de dados.

Atente-se a checar se esse retorno é `null` antes de acessar suas propriedades, evitando `NullPointerException`, e também verifique se o valor passado por `txtID` não seja vazio ou um valor que não possa ser convertido para `int`, evitando exceções do tipo `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: Obrigado, Diego.

Answer (score 1):

Substitua:

```
 Agenda a = new Agenda();
 a.setId(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
 ga.selecionar(a.getId());
```

Por:

```
Agenda a = ga.selecionar(Integer.parseInt(txtID.getText()));
```